# API VK метод wall.post

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, post

Всем привет цель - постить на стену паблика вк из сайта, для этого выбрал Open API, но мне не критично в принципе. Для публикации использую метод wall.post но когда отправляется запрос то вылетает всплывающее окно авторизации, которое мне не нужно.

```
$(function(){

$('#Call').on('click', function() {
    VK.Api.call('wall.post', {
        owner_id: '-95639540',
        v:"5.73",
        message: "test"
    }, function(r) {
        if(r.response) {
            console.log( r );
        }
    });
})
```

});

Как избежать появления этого окна? Может через бекэнд? Пробовал втулить access_token дополнительным параметром (ну соответственно с полученным токеном) в объект параметров, но результат тот же всплывающее окно с авторизацией.

http://joxi.ru/823YX7CJ9ZBlrO

Comment: может сначала токен получить нужно

Comment: Вадим " Пробовал втулить access_token дополнительным параметром (ну соответственно с полученным токеном) в объект параметров, но результат тот же всплывающее окно с авторизацией." я же написал что пробовал с токеном

Comment: Этот токен нужно добавить в объект параметров верно?

Comment: "https: //oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=6499596&display=page&scope=wall&response_type=token&v=5.78" ну вот к примеру в моем случае ссылка для получения токена, полученный токен я кладу в объект параметров под ключем "access_token" и значением соответственно полученного токена но в итоге все равно получаю всплывающее окно при посте

Comment: Без окна — только для Standalone/Desktop приложений, пересоздавайте

Comment: Так у меня Standalone ну сейчас пересоздам

Comment: http://joxi.ru/82QXlnCjwl0Omd вот пересоздал но тот же эффект